# Need something to give me a swap image on click behavior

Tags: javascript

I can use CSS or javascript but I've been struggling with it.  It needs to be an "on-click" behavior when you click on the number in the lower right corner... like this one:  http://www.winteradagency.com/mrw/images/residential2.jpg
So that when you click on #1 you get the first photo, #2 the 2nd one and so on...
Any ideas?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Without showing what you've tried, I'm a little reluctant to just give you the answer. You'll learn more if I don't. If you provide code and show where you're stuck and such, well, that's a different story.*

That being said, if you want to use jQuery, there are some nice plugins that have a similar functionality to what you want. One of them being [Easy Slider](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider). Here's also a list of [15 jQuery Image Gallery Plugins](http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/03/15-amazing-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins-and-tutorials/) that I got from doing a quick google search.

Comment: That's perfect.  I'll use easy slider.  I was trying to do it using Fireworks and just couldn't get it to work.  I went to jQuery and couldn't find the right thing using their search feature.  This is just what I needed.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not create four buttons and align it to right end, and everytime the image changes you update the text of the buttons. Each button could simply update the image to the one corresponding to its number.

Comment: so it would be an arrow or something signifying they could move to the next image?